# Can we use Apama to monitor networking tcp/udp(IP) traffic and generate events?

Tags: apama

Can we use Apama to monitor Networking IP traffic and generate events based on that? 
we are planning to use Apama to monitor networking traffic and based on the generated events  decisions will be made to scale up or scale-down particular applications on our cloud. Is it possible only with APAMA or we need any additional software components to achieve this goal?

Also where to get "SoftwareAG designer" with linux version of Apama community edition?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to answer your last question first. Unfortunately right now we don't have a Linux version of Designer. We do ship syntax hilighting files for some common editors (emacs, vi) and in the 10.3.1 release due to be released on the community site next week we will have a tool called apama_project which can generate projects similar to Designer.

The question about networking IP traffic is more interesting. In principle this is a reasonable thing to monitor in Apama, however you will need some way to get the network traffic into Apama - we don't have a library to do that built in. The best way would probably be to write a connectivity plugin in C++ (the API is publicly available as part of the product to write your own) which uses a library like libpcap to read the network traffic and put it into Apama. Once the events are in Apama then you can write EPL to track them and make decisions and then use either a standard plugin like the HTTP REST client or another custom transport to call out to your cloud scaling system.

HTH
Matt

Comment: Regarding Designer for Linux: Is it not available only for Apama community edition or even the commercial edition also? Because we have a valid Apama license, when we tried to install Apama on Windows machine we got to see Apama as part of installed products in the welcome page of the designer. On Linux we are able to launch the designer(eclipse) but there is no Apama as part of the installed product list in the welcome page.

Comment: We also only support Designer on Windows in the commercial version I'm afraid. If you have a licence you could try submitting a support request to get it on product management's roadmap - customer demand is the only way that's likely to happen